# Button not working for the second time in DT table shiny

Tags: shiny

In the below application, the edit works fine for the first time. (Say you click on first row button, it works fine. But once you cancel and again click on same button, it is not working)

Can anyone help me here? Is it related to binding ?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("df")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  output$df <- renderDataTable({
    iris$Edit = shinyInput(actionButton, nrow(iris), 'button_', label = "Edit", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' )
    datatable(iris, escape = F) 
  })

  observeEvent(input$select_button,{
     selectedRow <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])

    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Edit", size = "l",
      fluidPage(width = 12,fluidRow(
        column(width = 3,selectedRow)
      )),
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"),actionButton("update", "Update"))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Add somewhere `observe(print(input$select_button))` and you should see why it is only working once. The `observeEvent(input$select_button...,{})` is triggered only when input$select_button change of value. BUT if you click twice on the same row, it doesn't change it's value because its value is based on the row. You need to find another way to define the button id I think.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this??

Comment: I think you can change the id of your button everytime you click on it for example. And its id would look like `select_button1_0` if never clicked, `select_button1_1` if clicked once etc ... This way you can still get the row number with str_split, and if you click a second time, `input$select_button1_X` won't be the exact same id as the previous click.

Comment: Oh I see. Can u please show a sample please

Comment: I would love to and I tried but I know no javascript at all. I am incapable of finding the piece of code to concatenate "this.id" and "_0" ( and i searched but not a lot ahah).

Answer (score 1):

You should change `this.id` to `this.id + "_" + Date.now()`.
When you generate unique `this.id`, it works properly.